# Box-Shadow for Mozilla not working

Tags: css, mozilla, shadow, box-shadow

I have this CSS code, but the shadow thing is not working in Mozilla Firefox:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    background-image: url("d3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    -moz-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px grey);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px grey);
}
```

It looks really nice in Chrome, all elements in the body have some kind of shadow and I want to achieve that in Mozilla too. How do I do this? Why is "moz" not working?

Thank you!

Comment: `all elements in body have a shadow` and yet you use that only on `body`

Comment: I'm sorry what? Yes, I use that only on `body` and it works for all elements (in Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `-moz-filter` for box-shadow. [Support for box-shadow](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) is almost fully supported. All modern browsers are good to go. Just `box-shadow` is fine. Although I'm not sure how well it'll behave on the body element.

That's probably why it's not working. Always include prefixed CSS first. Unprefixed last. Order is important in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

`box-shadow` and `drop-shadow` are not the same thing. `box-shadow` is, well... [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow). And `drop-shadow` is one of the values of the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property. As seen in [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter) the `filter` is fully supported by Firefox and doesn't need a prefix to use it.

So you just have to change the prefix and remove the `box-shadow` since it is an other, irrelevant property:

```
body {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Sans-serif;
    background-image: url("d3.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px grey);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 1px grey);
}
```